# minikube errors out in Windows10

Tags: windows, startup, minikube, kubernetes

Need your help with K8S. I am trying to restart an minikube VM via a Virtual Switch in Windows10. Its a single Node on my Laptop(64bit).

I tried removing the current VM from HyperV manager and recreating a new one with command - >

*minikube start --vm-driver hyperv --hyperv-virtual-switch "Primary Virtual Switch"*

But minikube errors out saying config.json is not found. Do i need to reinstall minikube again to overcome this error. What could have gone wrong?? I didnt get to do a "minikube stop" previously before my laptop shutdown. Could this have messed up the configs?  I didnt find any Config file in the JSON path it is looking for in the error.

[Error Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8wnP.png)

Request your kind help.

Comment: Forget it - removed the .minikube folder and initiated the iso download to get over the issue. Bug exists for sure.

Answer (score 0):

As advised in error please try once with following command.

```
Minikube delete
```

and then

```
minikube start --vm-driver hyperv --hyperv-virtual-switch "Primary Virtual Switch"
```

usually minikube's config files resides in ~.minikube\machines\minikube. Please check once there too.